# Polymorphic function list of tuples

Tags: sml

Given a list of type (real * 'a) list. I want first of all to find the largest real in the list and then for the largest real return the corresponding 'a. Can anyone give me a hint. I have tried to make a pattern

```
((x1,x2),(y1,y2) :: xs) = if x1 > largest((y1,y2)::xs) then x2 else y2.
```

I did not write the entire function since I am om my phone. I have taken care of the empty list and list with one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one is what you are looking for? Please note that the case for the empty list is still missing, which gives you a compiler warning.

```
fun largest ((x1,x2) :: nil) = x2
  | largest ((x1,x2) :: (y1,y2) :: xs) = 
    if y1 > x1 then 
      largest((y1,y2) :: xs) 
    else 
      largest((x1,x2) :: xs) 

val max = largest [(1.0,"a"), (4.0, "b"), (4.0, "c"), (3.0, "d")]
```

Gives you: max = "b"

Comment: Is there a way to do it without foldl?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have not learned about higher order functions i.e. cases, NONE and SOME. Can you give me a tip on how to do it without them?